# how to find the last day of each month in a data frame using R

Tags: r

i now have a data frame which the month and day are in different columns.
How should i write the code to get exactly the last day of each month?

```
The data is like:
Month    Day
1        1
1        2
1        3
2        1
2        5
```

Thanks!!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `aggregate`

```
aggregate(Day ~Month, df1, FUN = max)
```

---

If the 'Month', 'Day' are already ordered

```
df1[!duplicated(df1$Month, fromLast = TRUE),]
#   Month Day
#3     1   3
#5     2   5
```

---

A `tidyverse` approach would be

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    group_by(Month) %>%
    slice(n())  # assumes the 'Day' is ordered
```

If the 'Day' is not ordered, get the `max`

```
df1 %>%
    group_by(Month) %>%
    summarise(Day = max(Day))
```

Answer (score 1):

```
library(sqldf)
sqldf("select max(Day),Month from df1 group by Month")
```

or

```
library(Hmisc)
summarize(df1$Day,df1$Month,max)
```